# Get 64 & 32 bit Providers in 64 Bit .Net

Tags: .net, 32bit-64bit

I have a simple winforms utility that detects available database providers using the following code:

```
var test = System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses();
```

This works well to get either 64-bit or 32-bit providers when built for 64-bit or 32-bit architectures, but is there any way to get both the 64-bit AND 32-bit providers when built just for 64-bit? Since this is a utility for testing connections, both architectures are required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code to get the 32 bit providers in my 64 bit code. The same method is used to get 64 bit providers in 32 bit code. I'm unsure exactly how universal this code is, but it has worked for each machine I have tried.

```
_dtProviders = DBCore.GetAvailableProviders();  // Col 2 is Name, Col 1 is description
List<string> providers = new List<string>();

string version = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetSystemVersion();

if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
{
    foreach (DataRow item in _dtProviders.Rows)
    {
        providers.Add(item.ItemArray[2].ToString());
    }

    string fPath = "C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\" + version + "\\Config\\machine.config";
    if (File.Exists(fPath))
    {

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(fPath);
        XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//configuration//system.data//DbProviderFactories");
        foreach (XmlNode nod in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            var attr = nod.Attributes["invariant"].Value;
            if (attr != null)
            {
                if (!providers.Contains(attr))
                {
                    providers.Add(attr + " (32 Bit)");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Warning: Could not locate machine config file load 32-Bit providers. No file located at '" + fPath + "'" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```